# LinkedIn OAuth token with Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, oauth, sdk, linkedin-jsapi

I was integrating **LinkedIn sign-in** with my web application,

Initially I was doing the implementation using JS SDK. After I realised that for iOS Mobile Devices, LinkedIn does not support JS SDK. So Currently I am using OAuth implementation.

My question is,  `Is there any way to use JS SDK after getting OAuth login success and after getting the access token`. My point is, `I don't want to do the logic for token validation, expiration etc`.

PS - Similar feature I have found in Facebook SDK, they are allowing to use Facebook JS SDK after setting the access token to SDK.

Please share your thoughts, comments, links.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are using JS SDK, which has all of the following features to work with authorization, tokens etc.

Example:

```
IN.User.authorize()
IN.User.logout()
IN.User.refresh()
IN.API.RAW.... etc
```

Comment: How do we get access token in client side?

Comment: @Sankar IN library makes authentication request and then puts in localstorage that token or maybe server sets cookie

Comment: can you please share some sample code to get access token via JavaScript

Comment: @Sankar check LinkedIn library. It should be there

Comment: @Tyrcheg: As I have seen, Linkedin JS lib not supporting any of the token related logic. Auth tokens only can get through oAuth.

Comment: @Sankar: It is better to go with OAuth if you are targeting iOS devices.